# How to validate presense of a value based on an API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I've got a model `@record_request` that takes in a unique identifier and saves it to the database - the model can be later used to fire a bunch of API requests off to an external database to do it's work.

Thing is, I don't want the user to be able to save the value in the Rails app, if it can't be queried in the remote database.

I've tried creating validations and creating Rspec tests, but all of them require my `@current_user` variable with all the `api_token` and `referesh_token` and other OmniAuth goodies needed to make an autenticated API call...

So I'm kind of stumped. Where is the best practice place to put a validation rule of this kind.

I'm thinking I'll have to put something in my controller on `:create` that makes the call there and raises errors/flashes that way... but then it seems like I've got a load of code on my controller, and I've fallen for a [fat controller anti-pattern](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model), no?

What is the best practice?

Comment: Both [toddmetheny's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1378252/toddmetheny) and [Druid's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3172183/druid) solutions worked, I ended up using Druid's in code though so hit answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from a project I'm working on, this code is written in the model

```
  after_validation :should_validate_match?,  on: [:create, :update]


  def should_validate_match?
    if self[:type] == 'Match'
      self.answers.each{|ans| self.errors.add(:answer, "match cannot be null") if ans.match.blank?}
    end

    self.errors.empty?
  end
```

Comment: Interesting, so this is running from the controller (based on [:create, :update]?), how does that work with the after_validation method? Wouldn't that be an ActiveModel thing?

Comment: No, the callbacks is set in the model, try to use this and tell me what happens on the create/update

Comment: Would you mind unpacking for me the line `self.answers.each`, guessing both `answers` and `type` are fields off your model? Does that store an array or something that you iterate over to add errors to an individual element?

Comment: self here is our current object, this object is associated to model "Answer" in one to many relation

Comment: I'm accessing the errors in case if the if condition is valid, `:answer` here is part of the error message, I return true if `self.errors` is empty, else i return false

Answer (score 1):

You could test the authentication in custom method triggered by a `before_save` callback in your model.

Something like:

```
before_save :do_this

def do_this
  if name_of_attribute.blank?
    return
  else
    # api call to test authentication
  end     
end
```

If a record request has a reference to user you shouldn't need access to the `current_user` helper.

Comment: `api_call_to_test_authentication  unless name_of_attribute.blank?`  will be cleaner for your instance.

Comment: Yeah i think this is an interesting bet, but this would be a private method from within my controller, right? You're not worried about that being an antipattern? If it's in the model i still get the problem of how/should it be accessing the session / `@current user` stuff

Comment: Nope. Callbacks go in the model. If you can't save a user_id on the object, you can also just call the method from the controller and pass it current_user.

Comment: thanks, just read up [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) makes far more sense now